# How can I access dynamically assigned images?

Tags: javascript

First question ever; I'm only a beginner, so excuse my ignorance! 
Scenario: JavaScript memory card game. I created an imageArray and after shuffling the cards created this loop to add the images to the cards.

```
for(i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i++) {
        cardImage = imageArray[i];
        $('.flip-card-front').eq(i).attr('src', cardImage);
    }
```

But, I can't for the life of me work out how to access the 'src' attribute value, which I want to use in my card match function. [Images placed on cloudinary]

```
 $('.flip-card').click(function() {
        if(lockBoard) return;
        $(this).addClass('flipped');


        if(!cardFlipped) {
            cardFlipped = true;
            firstCard = this;
        } else {
            cardFlipped = false;
            secondCard = this;

            // If two cards have been flipped lock the board
            lockBoard = true;

           // Do the cards match?
           // Does firstCard src attr === secondCard src attr?

        };
```

I have tried `(this).attr('src')` and `(firstCard).attr('src')` and receive the error 'cannot read the property of undefined'.  I have also tried to access it through `.innerHTML:contains`. Nothing. I'm totally lost. Please help.

Comment: please, could you add some relevant HTML code to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `(this)` and `(firstCard)` are not defined here as you are expecting.

Try changing your:

`.click(function()`

To:

`.click(function(event)`

And get your card as:

`let firstCard = $(event.target);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  It doesn't work, unfortunately because the card back is initially facing the player.  I found the answer though.

Answer (score 0):

After much searching, I found the solution:

```
let firstCardImg = $(this).find(">:first-child").attr("src");
```